# haven't succed to create animation between two views

Tags: iphone, animation, scrollview

I want to create an animation between two views and here is what I did:

Both views containing the same `scrollView`, and the purpose of the animation between views is to create animation between the edges of the scrollView.

So here is what I did:

```
  UIView *view1;
    UIView *view2;

view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    self.scrollView1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 320)];
    self.scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView1.delegate = self;
    [view1 addSubview:scrollView1];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
```

And when the `scrollView` reaches the last frame:

```
  - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
//here I verify when the last frame of the scrollView is loaded
     if (self.scrollView1.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width*pathImages.count)         
        {      
            [view1 removeFromSuperview];
            [self.scrollView1 scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width,0 ,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:NO];

            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
            [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut  forView:view2 cache:YES];
            [view2 addSubview:scrollView1];
            [self.view addSubview:view2];
            [UIView commitAnimations];


        }
    }
```

The thing is that the scrollView is loaded from the first position again(as it should be) but with no animation-just appears suddenly.
Can someone tell me where is the mistake and a solution for it.Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
```

instead of:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
```

Usually the "UIViewAnimationOption*" are associated with the new, recommended block based syntax for animations.